# How to convert this tensorflow 1.0 code to tensorflow 2.0 when the upgrade script fails?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have the following tensorflow 1.0 code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

feature_cols = tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X_train)
dnn_clf = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[300,100], n_classes=10,
                                         feature_columns=feature_cols)
dnn_clf = tf.contrib.learn.SKCompat(dnn_clf)  # if TensorFlow >= 1.1
dnn_clf.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=50, steps=40000)
```

When I try to run the converter:

```
tf_upgrade_v2 --infile mlp.py --outfile mlp2.py
```

I get the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File: mlp.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mlp.py:3:15: ERROR: Using member tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input in 
deprecated module tf.contrib. tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input cannot be converted automatically. tf.contrib will not be distributed with TensorFlow 2.0, please 
consider an alternative in non-contrib TensorFlow, a community-maintained repository such as 
tensorflow/addons, or fork the required code.
mlp.py:4:10: ERROR: Using member tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier in deprecated module tf.contrib. tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier cannot be converted automatically. tf.contrib will not be distributed with TensorFlow 2.0, please consider an alternative in non-contrib TensorFlow, a community-maintained repository such as tensorflow/addons, or fork the required code.
mlp.py:6:10: ERROR: Using member tf.contrib.learn.SKCompat in deprecated module tf.contrib. tf.contrib.learn.SKCompat cannot be converted automatically. tf.contrib will not be distributed with TensorFlow 2.0, please consider an alternative in non-contrib TensorFlow, a community-maintained repository such as tensorflow/addons, or fork the required code.
```

My question is: **How to convert this tensorflow 1.0 code to tensorflow 2.0 when the upgrade script fails?**

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Tensorflow 1.x libraries are moved to `Tensorflow/addons` and few of them are replaced with `Tensorflow.Estimator` in Tensorflow 2.x.
`tf_upgrade_v2` script will not completely upgrade code from Tfv1.x to Tfv2.x.
This script will accelerate your upgrade process by converting existing TensorFlow 1.x Python scripts to TensorFlow 2.0.

In this case `tf.contrib.learn` is replaced with Estimator.

**TF2.x compatible code:**
Replace

```
tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedRegressor
```

with

```
tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedRegressor
```

Take a look at this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-move-from-tf-contrib-learn-estimator-to-core-tensorflow-tf-estimator-af07b2d21f34) for more information